# How to set different freeze panes for different sheets in an Excel using VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to set different freeze panes for different sheets in an Excel. I tried using the below code but this is being assigned to all sheets. But I want to freeze first 6 rows in my first sheet and only top row in second sheet. I tried so many ways but no result. Any suggestions?

```
With xlApp.ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 6
End With
```

The full code (from comments) is:

```
Dim xlApp As Application 
Dim xlWb As Workbook 
'Dim xlWs As Worksheet 
xlApp = New Application() 
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csFileName) 
With xlApp.ActiveWindow 
  .SplitColumn = 0 
  .SplitRow = 6 
End With
```

Comment: You have to activate the sheet in question, then freeze (or split in your code).

Comment: How can i know which sheet is active?

Comment: Test `activesheet.name` for example

Comment: I tried giving the sheet name directly. Even then no luck!

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little more detail than "no luck". What exactly did you try and what exactly happened?

Comment: `Dim xlApp As Application                                                                          Dim xlWb As Workbook                                                                              xlApp = New Application()                                                                 xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csFileName)                                      With xlApp.ActiveWindow                                                                                       .SplitColumn = 0 .SplitRow = 6 End With`

Comment: This is my code. Using this only my first sheet rows are freezing. I want to freeze only top row of my second sheet

Comment: Then you need to activate that sheet first: `xlwb.sheets(2).activate`. You're also missing some `Set` statements if this is really VBA and not VB.Net...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, replacing the sheet names, rows & columns with the appropriate values:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").activate
ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 0
Activewindow.SplitRow = 6

Worksheets("Sheet2").activate
ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 5
Activewindow.SplitRow = 11

Worksheets("Sheet3").activate
ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 10
Activewindow.SplitRow = 16
```

Based on the code you posted in comments, this should work:

```
Dim xlApp As Application 
Dim xlWb As Workbook 
xlApp = New Application() 
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csFileName) 
xlwb.worksheets("Sheet1").activate
With xlApp.ActiveWindow 
  .SplitColumn = 0 
  .SplitRow = 6 
End With
xlwb.worksheets("Sheet2").activate
With xlApp.ActiveWindow 
  .SplitColumn = 0 
  .SplitRow = 1
End With
```

I would recommend *always* explicitly specifying which sheet you want active for this, since it requires `ActiveWindow` in order to function, that way you won't ever accidentally be on the wrong window when you're setting your split rows.

```
Dim xlApp As Application 
Dim xlWb As Workbook 
xlApp = New Application() 
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csFileName) 
xlwb.worksheets("Sheet1").activate
xlWb.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A6").select
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes
xlwb.worksheets("Sheet2").activate
xlWb.worksheets("Sheet2").range("A2").select
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes
```

Comment: I tried. but I am getting an error. The compiler is not identifying "ActiveWindow".

Comment: I just executed that code in a brand new workbook and it ran just fine. Is this in a workbook you've created in code, or is it in an existing workbook that you open and run the code against?

Comment: I am creating a new workbook. When I try to execute this code. it says `Worksheets is a type and cannot be used an expression`

Comment: Yeah, there's something about that. I initially tried `Worksheets("Sheet1").SplitColumn`, and that doesn't work. The `Split*` methods only work on `ActiveWindow`, and there may be something about how you're creating the workbook that's preventing it from working properly here. Add your workbook create code to your original question so we can see more of what's going on.

Comment: This is my code. `Dim xlApp As Application
        Dim xlWb As Workbook
        'Dim xlWs As Worksheet
            xlApp = New Application()
            xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csFileName)
            With xlApp.ActiveWindow
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 6
            End With`  My stored procedure is returning two tables. I want to freeze first six rows in sheet 1 and only top row in sheet 2. Using the above code only sheet 1 rows are freezing.

Comment: I executed the code. The second sheet top row got freezed. But the problem is in the first sheet now. Instead of getting top 6 rows freezed the page is divided into two and two copies of tables are present in two divided parts. Am not sure why this is happening

Comment: because all sections of the spreadsheet are scrollable when you use any combination of `.SplitColumn` and `.SplitRow`. If you actually want to programmatically use _freeze panes_, then see the 3rd edit to my answer. Note that `Freeze Panes` is _different_ than `SplitWindow`.

Comment: Am a bit confused here. how come `.SplitColumn` and `.SplitRow` is used in freezing rows, if they are meant for splitting/diving a sheet? I have seen a bunch of examples. Most of them used `.SplitColumn` and `.SplitRow` for freezing rows. Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: The `Split`s give you scrollable windows allowing you to look at any two (or four) areas of your spreadsheet at the same time. `Freeze` holds fixed the top row(s) and/or left-hand column(s). If you tried out my 3rd update, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Yeah I know the difference but My question is how come the `.SplitColumn` and `.SplitRow` is used in freezing panes if they are generally used in splitting?

Comment: I tried the code you recently posted but I am getting an exception at Line 7 - `Public member 'FreezePanes' on type 'Workbook' not found`

Comment: Bah! Left `ActiveWindow.` out. Note the changes to the two lines with `.FreezePanes`

Comment: Its working in both sheets!! But in the second sheet instead of top row, first 18 rows are being freezed :-(

Comment: Have you tried to play around with the code to see if you can figure out why?

Comment: Hey it worked. Instead of A1, if we give A2 then it works!! Thank you so much for helping me. Really appreciated!!